How to use timeout in Twitchio?
I tried to give the user to timeout. In the Twitchio.dev documentation, I found that the User class has the timeout_user command, but I don't understand how to use it.
I found the following solution on the Internet:
ctx.channel.timeout(ctx.author.name , time, reason)

but this does not work because the timeout is not contained in the channel.
later I found a solution that looks much simpler.:
ctx.send(f'/timeout {ctx.author.name} time reason')

As I understand it, the bot just needs to send a timeout command to the chat. However, it is ignored
